# Prove $V = \{y : \rho(x, y) > r \}$ is open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Here is my question:

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space, $x \in X$  and $r > 0$. Prove $V = \{y : \rho(x, y) > r \}$ is open.

I'm struggling to find a way to prove this because of the $\rho(x, y) > r$ condition. I'm new to learning topologies, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The triangle inequality shows that the map $y\mapsto \rho(x,y)$ is continuous, the result follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $V$ is just the set of all points in the space with a distance greater of $r$ from $x$, right?

So, in drawing, $V$ is the blue part (it does not necessarily look like this, it is only to illustrate ideas and that not everything magically arises).

To show that $V$ is open, we need to find, for any $y \in V$, an open ball around $y$ that is totally contained in $V$. Of course, if we see below, the most natural thing that one can think of is to take the ball around $y$ of radius the distance from $y$ to the red point.

This distance is given by: 
$$d := \rho(x,y) - r.$$
We claim that $B(y,d)$, the ball around $y$ with radius $d$, is contained in $V$. To see this, pick $z \in B(y,d)$ and we need to see that $z$ is in $V$ (that is, we need to see that $\rho(x,z) > r$).

Now, $z \in B(y,d)$ simply means that $\rho(y,z)<d = \rho(x,y) - r$, and using the reverse triangle inequality we obtain that
$$\rho(x,z) \geq \rho(x,y) - \rho(y,z)>r$$
which proves our claim.

[image: open]

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to explain, it really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use triangle inequality to show that if $y_0 \in V$ then $B(y_0, s) \subseteq V$ provided $0<s<\frac {\rho (x,y_0)-r} 2$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll elaborate my comment. Consider the map $X\to \mathbb R$ defined by $y\mapsto \rho(x,y)$. Then, $\rho(x,z) \le \rho(x,y) + \rho(y,z)$, and by switching $y$ and $z$ we obtain $|\rho(x,y) - \rho(x,z)| \le \rho(y,z)$, it follows that the map is (uniformly) continuous, the set in the op is just the inverse image of the open set $(r,\infty)\subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: thank you so much!